# How to require approval to signup new Bluespice MediaWiki accounts?

Tags: mediawiki, authentication

On a MediaWiki site running BlueSpice, how can I require that all new account sign ups be approved before the account is created?

I tried adding the [ConfirmAccount extension described here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ConfirmAccount), but now on account creation I just get  a database error:

> A database query error has occurred. This may indicate a bug in the software.

Perhaps this extension is not compatible with BlueSpice?

---

The database error was due to not running the update.php script that is part of the ConfirmAccount extension.  Once that is run, the error goes away.

However, while the `Special:RequestAccount` page now works, a user can just go to `Special:RequestAccount` and create an account without any issues.  Perhaps Bluespice is in conflict with ConfirmAccount and is allowing the account to be created?

How do I disable the account creation as the Login page so users must request an account be created for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was in interaction between Bluespice and ConfirmAccount, to get it working properly, I had to go into the Bluespice `Permission Manager` to edit the permissions of the group `*` to drop the `CreateAccount` permission in the `Wiki` column that was enabled by default.